# Как настроить выпадающий список в xlsx через Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

Кто знает как можно и можно ли настроить выпадающий список в excel через Pandas? Направьте, пожалуйста, в нужном направлении, что и где посмотреть, если в курсе.

Суть вот в чем:
Я собираю десятки файлов xlsx в едином формате пробегая циклом в папке на диске, далее объединяю все файлы в один DataFrame, затем провожу некоторые манипуляции с данными, а потом мне необходимо этот DataFrame разбить снова на десятки xlsx файлов и направить далее сотрудникам, НО пара колонок в этих xlsx у меня должны быть с выпадающими списками и я не знаю как мне это сделать.
...заходить в каждый excel после его получения из python и настраивать этот выпадающий список это очень долго.

Спасибо!

На данный момент посмотрел документацию Pandas, не смог найти подходящие приемы и параметры под свою задачу((

Comment: `посмотрел документацию Pandas, не смог найти подходящие приемы` - потому что такого там нет. Можно воспользоваться "родным" [VBA](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/data-validation-drop-down-lists-in-vba/) или подходящими библиотеками для Python, например [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_data_validation.html), [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validation.html)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, буду тогда "копать" по этим двум библиотекам.

Answer (score 0):

Слушай, в Django можно реализовать обновление данных в таблице без перезагрузки страницы с помощью **JavaScript и AJAX-запросов.**

1. Нужно создать шаблон, содержащий таблицу, которую ты хочешь обновлять. Добавь id элементу таблицы или класс, чтобы использовать его в JavaScript.

```html
<table id="my-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Заголовок столбца</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for item in items %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.data }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

2. Добавь JavaScript код, который будет обновлять таблицу. Используйте функцию `setInterval`, чтобы обновлять таблицу каждые несколько секунд или минут.

```js
<script>
    function updateTable() {
        var table = document.getElementById("my-table");
        var url = "{% url 'update_table' %}";  // Замените 'update_table' на нужный вам URL-шаблон, отвечающий за обновление таблицы

        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                // Очищаем текущую таблицу
                while (table.rows.length > 1) {
                    table.deleteRow(1);
                }

                // Добавляем новые строки
                data.forEach(item => {
                    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
                    cell.innerHTML = item.data;
                });
            });
    }

    setInterval(updateTable, 5000);  // Обновляем таблицу каждые 5 секунд
</script>
```

3. В представлении Django, соответствующем URL-шаблону `update_table`, получи новые данные из базы данных и верните их в виде JSON-ответа.

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import Item

def update_table(request):
    items = Item.objects.all().values('data')  # Замените 'Item' и 'data' на нужные вам модель и поле

    return JsonResponse(list(items), safe=False)
```

4. Не забудь создать URL-шаблон для 'update_table' в файле `urls.py` вашего приложения Django.

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # Другие URL-шаблоны
    path('update_table/', views.update_table, name='update_table'),
]
```

Теперь таблица будет обновляться автоматически без перезагрузки страницы.

Обрати внимание, что в моем приведенном выше примере обновление данных происходит каждые 5 секунд. Ты можешь настроить этот интервал по своим потребностями. Также учти, что код приведен лишь в качестве примера, и тебе может потребоваться внести некоторые изменения в зависимости от твоей конкретной реализации.